# JWT Symfony 6 Can't get a way to read the property "username" in class "App\Entity\User"

Tags: php, symfony, jwt, symfony6

When I implement JWT have a error: [image]

My security.yml:

```
security:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            json_login:
                check_path: api_login
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
            jwt: ~

            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#the-firewall

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        - { path: ~/api/login, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }

when@test:
    security:
        password_hashers:
            # By default, password hashers are resource intensive and take time. This is
            # important to generate secure password hashes. In tests however, secure hashes
            # are not important, waste resources and increase test times. The following
            # reduces the work factor to the lowest possible values.
            Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
                algorithm: auto
                cost: 4 # Lowest possible value for bcrypt
                time_cost: 3 # Lowest possible value for argon
                memory_cost: 10 # Lowest possible value for argon
```

I have current error (Can't get a way to read the property "username" in class "App\Entity\User") when entered correct creds, but when I enter invalid creds I have correct error about invalid creds. What I do wrong?

Comment: Add 'username' property to User entity and issue was fixed

Answer (score 0):

In your security.yml, change `property: email` to `property: username`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with providers property inside your **security.yaml** file, just change:

```
app_user_provider:
 entity:
   class: App\Entity\User
   property: email
```

to

```
 app_user_provider:
   entity:
     class: App\Entity\User
     property: username
```

**EDIT:**

I have had the same problem with symfony 6.08, 6.09 and 6.1,
just add this fucntion inside user entity:

```
public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

config/packages/lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml

```
user_identity_field: getEmail
```

Comment: Your answer only contains code. I recommend that you don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.